# Pentaho CDE Dashboard not scrollable on ipad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, scroll, pentaho, pentaho-cde

we are currently using Pentaho with a CDE Dashboard on bootstrap template. When opening the Dashboard in Pentaho Mobile or in Safari/Chrome on an iPad 2 we are unable to scroll down on the Dashboard.

We already tried the fixes provided in the Pentaho forums (e.g. http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?131973-Pentaho-4-5-CE-and-iPAD-(no-scrolling-inside-mantle-tabs) and http://redmine.webdetails.org/issues/2850) but this does not work.

tested software versions:
Pentaho BI Server: 5.1 and 5.2, currently 5.2.0.2.84
Pentaho CDE: v14.07.29
Pentaho Mobile App: newest version for Pentaho 5
iPad Version: 2, updated

The code we use:

```
var applyScroll = function() {
    var zoom, height = $(window.top).height();
    $('body').css({'height': height, 'overflow-y': 'scroll', 'webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'});
    (Math.abs(window.top.orientation) == 90 ) ? zoom = '100%' : zoom = '78%';
    $('.container').first().css('zoom', zoom);
} 

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) && (window.innerHeight != window.top.innerHeight)) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        applyScroll();
    });
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        applyScroll();
    });
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve the issue?